# I am unable to receive cookie from express backend to react frontend using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

```js
const express = require("express");
// const storiesRouter = require("./routes/storiesRouter")
// const postsRouter = require("./routes/postsRouter");
// const usersRouter = require("./routes/usersRouter");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const validator = require("validator");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Name is required"],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Email is required"],
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
      validate: [validator.isEmail, "Provide Valid email"],
    },
    img: {
      data: Buffer,
      contentType: String,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["user", "lead-guide", "admin"],
      default: "user",
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Password is required"],
      minlength: 8,
      select: false,
    },
    passwordConfirm: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Confirm Password is required"],
      validate: {
        //Only works on create() or save()
        validator: function(el) {
          return el === this.password;
        },
        message: "Password are not same",
      },
    },
    passwordChangedAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
    passwordResetToken: String,
    passwordResetExpires: Date,
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
      select: false,
    },
  });
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

const app = express();

// cookieParser middleware
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3001",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/v1/users/login", async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("body", req.body);
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  console.log(email, password);
  if (!email || !password) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      message: "Please provide email and password",
    });
  }
  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select("+password");

  if (!user || !(await user.correctPassword(password, user.password))) {
    res.status(401).json({
      status: "fail",
      message: "Incorrect email and password",
    });
  }
  const token = signToken(user._id);
  req.user = user;
  console.log(token);
  res.cookie("jwt", token, { httpOnly: true, secure: false });
  res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    token,
  });
  console.log("res", res);
});

const signToken = (id) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
  });
};
```

I have tried to add all the code from different files and please manage if something got missing.

```js
const LoginFetch = async (methods, dataurl, loginInfo) => {
  let data = {};
  let fetchError = null;

  await axios(
    {
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/login",
      data: { email: loginInfo.email, password: loginInfo.password },
    },
    {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  )
    .then((dataRec) => {
      data = dataRec;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      fetchError = err;
    });
  return data;
};
```

I am setting cookie in express backend but it is not showing in react frontend but if i am fetching using thunder client it is setting cookie.

I am showing you the working

Axios request -[this is axios request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkiQw.png)

Login middleware - [you can see i am consoling response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOq78.png)

Response - [in response cookies = object null proptype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZlj1.png)

But i am getting response success in browser - [console the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTqif.png)

Now if i fetch using thunder-client cookies is getting setup - [thunder client req and console the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3b9X.png)

My app.js in server has cookie parser - [app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzhc9.png)

I have enabled third party cookie as well on chrome.
I am working on it from 2 days and cant receive cookie, please help!

Comment: Dear Aditya, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Instead of images, please provide code.

Comment: @technophyle — Err. Yes, it is. That's why `Set-Cookie` is an HTTP response header.

Comment: [Pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) or of [exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) are not very helpful. They don't show up in searches, may be blocked for users on networks without access to some other websites, and are invisible to screen readers / braille keyboards / etc. Put a [mcve] and (if applicable) text of the exception in the question itself. The editor has buttons and [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to help you format it so it is readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try using credentials and origin is of your domain like localhost or any deployed site host

from backend setup credentials is must and origin

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://your-react-app-domain.com',
  credentials: true  // This is crucial for cookie sharing
}));
```

from frontend pass credential to request

```
axios.get('http://your-backend-api-endpoint', {
  withCredentials: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks but I have already added this in cors options and axios option you can check above, now i have added code snippets.